# How to send message from user in telegram in web application?

Tags: python, django, telegram

I am trying to create web application using Python3.x and Django2.x.
I am creating `view` that authorizes the user in telegram, but when I get secure code and send it to function `sign_in()`, I receive an error "You also need to provide a phone_code_hash."

I don't know what is the `phone_code_hash`, and where I can get it.

**views.py:**

```
phone_code_hash = None

def authorize_user(request):
    global phone_code_hash
    if request.method == 'POST':
        secure_code = request.POST.get('secure_code')

        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        api_id = request.POST.get('api_id')
        api_hash = request.POST.get('api_hash')

        client = TelegramClient('spamer', api_id, api_hash)

        if secure_code:
            try:
                client.sign_in(phone, secure_code, phone_code_hash=phone_code_hash)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                return JsonResponse({'status': 0, 'error': 'error'})
            return JsonResponse({'status': 2})
        client.connect()
        phone_code_hash = client.send_code_request(phone).phone_code_hash

        return JsonResponse({'status': 1})

    return render(request, 'spamer/add_user.html')
```

I use `telethon` library for API interaction.
Maybe someone from you know how to authorize user and send message from him many times in different days. Maybe you suggest more suitable library or to use API requests with `urllib`.
I only want to authorize user and use him to send many messages to another people, is it real?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the telegram client [source](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/telegram_client.py#L351):

> phone_code_hash: The hash returned by .send_code_request.

so you need to call `client.send_code_request(phone)` before sign_up, this will set hash_code [automatically](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/telegram_client.py#L201) or you can save it and use later:

```
phone_code_hash = client.send_code_request(phone).phone_code_hash
```

Comment: In my view I use `client.send_code_request(phone)`, this views runs twice, first when i send code, after that ajax send request with code result, I will try to store this hash and use it later

Comment: @Vladyslav you can use session: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: How Django session can help me to keep Telegram Api session? I can serve in django session all data, but relation with telegram can be broken, and I will authenticate this user again

Comment: After your suggest i have another error: `Tried to invoke without .connect()`